# Rspec login before each example in a system test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I've got a system spec in a Rails 6 project where I need to login to be able to go through the examples. I've tried to do that inside a `before(:each)` block like so:

```rb
let(:user) { create(:user) }

before(:each) do
  login(user)
end
```

However that doesn't open up a browser and do the initial steps for logging in. I've searched but couldn't really find anything about why that wouldn't work. Hence I had to use that `login` function inside every example in my spec file. Is that the way to do it or is there any other way which is better?

```rb
# spec/support/session_helper.rb
module SessionHelper
  def login(user)
    visit login_path
    fill_in 'name', with: user.name
    fill_in 'password', with: user.password

    click_on 'Login'
  end
end
```

```rb
# spec/rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include SessionHelper
end
```

```rb
# spec/system/products_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Products", type: :system do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:product) { build(:product) }

  it 'visits the products page' do
    login(user)

    visit products_path
    expect(page).to have_content('Products')
  end

  it 'creates a Product' do
    login(user)

    visit products_path
    click_on 'New Product'

    fill_in 'Title', with: product.title
    fill_in 'Description', with: product.description
    fill_in 'Image url', with: product.image_url
    fill_in 'product_integer_price', with: product.price

    click_on 'Create Product'

    expect(page).to have_content('Product was successfully created')
    click_on 'Back'
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you use for authentication on the server side? Devise maybe?

Comment: I don't use any gem for authentication, it's just a simple `User` model with `has_secure_password`. I am currently following a book.

Comment: Whats the error message you get? It look's like this is a Capybara spec, so firstly make sure this gem is in your gemfile, secondly your `session_helper.rb` will need access to `rails_helper` if you want to use methods like `visit()`, so include `require "rails_helper"` at the top of the `session_helper.rb`

Comment: I don't get any error. Basically the test fails because the user is not logged in. That `login` method inside `before(:each)` is not even run, I mean only the things that interact with the browser are not run. For example `visit '/'`

Comment: `before(:each)` is exactly the way to do it. Is this block not executed at all or only the login method?

Comment: The block is executed, only the part where I do the login is not executed. So if I put a `puts 'foo'` inside before(:each) then that works. What I mean by "the part where I do the login" is where I interact with Capybara. The gem is in my Gemfile and in my spec I am already requiring 'rails_helper' so that would do it, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I've just trial & error and end up with the below code, the drawback that you need to control @session yourself and it's better to separate into a spec helper class or a `rspec shared context`. (`:selenium_chrome` is capybara driver for chrome, you can change another if you want)

```rb
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }

  before do
    @session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_chrome, YourAppName::Application)
    @session.visit(new_user_session_path)
    @session.find(:fillable_field, "name").set(user.name)
    @session.find(:fillable_field, "password").set(user.password)
    @session.click_button("Log-in")
  end

  it "should redirect to home page" do
    expect(@session.current_path).to eq "/"
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort! I am not sure whether what I want can be done. Some people say it's already the way it's done but I couldn't get it working and I was wondering the reason.

Comment: @AndréYuhai The reason that the code in before(:each) does not open up a browser window is Capybara use `RackTest` driver as default (so that driver in before scope is `RackTest`). But `RackTest is Capybara's default driver. It is written in pure Ruby and does not have any support for executing JavaScript.`  You can add `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome` in rails_helper and the code in before block will `animation` as you want. But one way or another, you need to control the `@session` by yourself.